# Keep routdata in generate urls to different controller (using anchor tag helper) in ASP NET MVC Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

At the startup.cs file, I have changed the default MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=home}/{company=-1}/{action=index}/{id?}");
```

It works properly when you create url links  (using the anchor tagHelper) from the same controller which you are visiting.

But I'm losing the Company value, when I create a link to another controller

```
<a asp-action="index" asp-controller="AnotherController" >TEST</a>
```

For example if I'm visiting http: // localhost/testcontroller/22     (Company=22)
The generated URL to another controllers is http:// localhost/AnotherController
The generated URL to the same controllers is correct: http:// localhost/testcontroller/22/otherAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if is the best practice, I could resolve it using the asp-route- prefix attribute.

```
<a asp-action="index" asp-controller="test" asp-route-company="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["company"]">TEST</a>
```